# My function is running but it's not displaying the pictures I'm holding in my array

Tags: arrays, image, carousel

I want to create a slideshow aka a carousel. However, I'm not seeing any images being displayed in the image element. I don't know where I've gone wrong.

```js
var i = 0
var time = 3000;
var images = new Array(3)
var slide = document.getElementById("slide")

images[0] = new Image();
images[0].src = "picture/michael-jordan.jpg"
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "picture/usain-bolt.jpg";
images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "picture/zidane.jpg"

console.log(images)

function changeImg() {
  slide.src = images[i];
  if(i < images.length - 1) {
    i++
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  setTimeout("changeImg()", time)
}

window.onload=changeImg;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>slideshow</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="slide" src="" alt="" width="400" height="200">
    <script src="index.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where I'm definitely expecting to see it is in the image element. But I'm not seeing any images being display. Please drop me a line if you know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CSS along with Javascript. Please take a look at this snippet.

> First, set the slideIndex to 1. (First picture)
>
> Then call showDivs() to display the first image.
>
> When the user clicks one of the buttons call plusDivs().
>
> The plusDivs() function subtracts one or  adds one to the slideIndex.
>
> The showDiv() function hides (display="none") all elements with the
> class name "mySlides", and displays (display="block") the element with
> the given slideIndex.
>
> If the slideIndex is higher than the number of elements (x.length),
> the slideIndex is set to zero.
>
> If the slideIndex is less than 1 it is set to number of elements
> (x.length).

source: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self

```
<img class="mySlides" src="img_snowtops.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg">
<img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg">



<button class="w3-button w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(+1)">&#10095;</button>

var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
 var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
```